# Displaying a check instead of a bool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, boolean

I am using MVC and have an Index View. One of the fields that is displayed is type Bool. Currently, it will display a True/False for its value however is there a way to display a check mark or a checked checkbox when True and nothing if False?

My Field -

```
public bool PrimaryContact { get; set; }
```

My View -

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Contacts)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@item.PrimaryContact</td>
                <td>@item.ContactType</td>
                <td>@item.Contact1</td>
           </tr>
      }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you absolutely want to show a checkbox, you can do this.

```
<td> <input type="checkbox" checked="@item.PrimaryContact" />  </td>
```

But a checkbox is a form input control. So if this is a view only screen, why not simply print "Yes" or "No" instead of the input control.

```
<td>@(item.PrimaryContact?"Yes":"No")</td>
```